# Location of object wrong?

Tags: transforms, units

So I just realized some strange stuff is happening when i export my object, and I realized the original object made in blender is not at center,

but the weird part is that its origin is at the center of the grid, the same as its armature but while the armature says its at 0, 0, 0, the objects position is 0, 0 , 2.40731.

if i apply location the origin of the object will go 2.4 units below

[image]

[image]

Im using Blender 2.71
Can anyone help?

[Blend file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=05600647048571993931&t=0560064704857199393131217)

Comment: when origin is 0,0,0 in transform but under the grind in the viewport it doesnt mess with exported animations so theres that.

Still its weird, is it some kinda bug?

Comment: Can you attach your blend file here?

Comment: Blend uploadaed

Answer (score 1):

Location is not "wrong".
Those numbers still represent the [global location of the origin of the object](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Properties), but location "on the screen" depends also from inherited transformation.

Let's make an example:

Consider two cube objects as the ones in the picture.

[image]

The active cube has X_location = 3

[image]

The parented cube has X_location = 2

But the are obiuvsly in the X location...this means that the child cube inherit the transformation of the parent object (the armature, whom origins is X location = 1 )

So the Cube children object origins is in X = 2, but as the parent object is in X = 1, it appear in X = 2+1 because inherit parent transformation.

You can easly see by un-parenting the object.

Comment: that cleared things up a bit, but still.
I unparented the mesh from the rig and saw that the origin of the mesh is way below the mesh when it should be at its feet. 
So i reposition the  mesh in edit mode, put it at 0 0 0, and parent again, and now the mesh and the origin are 2.4 units below. 

But the armature has 0 0 0 origin, and the mesh also, but somehow the mesh gets 2.4 underneath in the viewport if i parent it to the armature.

So where does the 2.4 come from? if they're both at 0 0 0?